# CURL command not working with simple HTTP GET but browser does

Tags: http, curl

I tried to fetch the data from `https://m.jetstar.com/Ink.API/api/flightAvailability?LocaleKey=en_AU&ChildPaxCount=0&DepartureDate=2016-03-21T00%3A00%3A00&ModeSaleCode=&Destination=NGO&CurrencyCode=TWD&AdultPaxCount=1&ReturnDate=&InfantPaxCount=0&Origin=TPE`

it couldn't be done by `curl -vv https://m.jetstar.com/Ink.API/api/flightAvailability?LocaleKey=en_AU&ChildPaxCount=0&DepartureDate=2016-03-21T00%3A00%3A00&ModeSaleCode=&Destination=NGO&CurrencyCode=TWD&AdultPaxCount=1&ReturnDate=&InfantPaxCount=0&Origin=TPE` it will return nothing,
However, browser can fetch whole data.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that "m.jetstar.com" is filtering requests that don't include the headers that a browser would send. Your curl statement needs to fully emulate a browser to get the data. One way to see what I'm saying is to open developer tools in Google Chrome, select the network tab, run the URL in the browser then goto to the row indicating the call and right click, then copy the request as a curl statement, then paste it to a notepad and you'll see all the additional headers you need. Additionally, that curl statement should work.

Comment: no it didn't work, given I use the fake `User-Agent` in Python, it still fetch empty data. `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36`

Comment: There are.more headers to consider beside User-Agent, if you do the copy paste frome chrome you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have set any HTTP_REQUEST variable for proxy settings. Verify by calling curl command in verbose mode. curl -v

I had setup a variable earlier and when I check the curl output in verbose mode it told me that it was going to proxy address. Once I deleted the HTTP_REQUEST variable from advanced system settings, it started working. Hope it helps.